# Apache ServiceMix! Request-Replay Web Service message

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, apache-camel, soapui

#### Hello!

I'm trying to learn some [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/) and [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and of course I've ran into some problems.

#### What I'm trying to do:

Send timed SOAP messages from ESB to some web service, wait for the reponse from the web service and process it. I'm using Apache ServiceMix!.

#### What I've done:

Implemented a WSDL file with two operations `PingOutput` (what I'm sending) and `PingInput` (what I want to receive from the WS).

Implemented a CXF Endpoint (`http://127.0.0.1:8090/ping_ws` is a WS mocked with SoapUI):

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8090/ping_ws"
                 id="Ping_Mocked_WS" wsdlURL="ping.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Implemented a Camel route:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true">
    <route id="ping-ws">
        <from uri="timer://ping_timer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000"/>
        <bean ref="PingBean" method="createPingRequest" />
        <to uri="cxf:bean:Ping_Mocked_WS"/>
        <bean ref="PingBean" method="processPingResponse" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

#### What I do not understand:

1. Why the `<bean ref="PingBean" method="processPingResponse" />` gets the correct response from SoapUI (the `PingOutput` operation defined in WSDL)?
2. Is this the correct way to achieve my goal? And by this way I mean with one single route?

The codes work correctly, I might have some typos here, please do not mind them.

#### Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1)

Likely because the type defined in the method signature of the processPingResponse method. Camel uses bean parameter binding, and based on the type, it uses its type converter to convert to the given type.

And as the payload is a SOAP response in XML it can use JAXB to convert from XML to the type from the method signature.

To do so it uses camel-jaxb which ServiceMix comes with out of the box.

Ad2)
The route works. What it is you want to do differently?

Comment: 1. I'll look into `camel-jaxb` documentation, hope to understand it better. 2. I don't want to do nothing to it, just didn't know if this was the right approach :). Thanks for the answer!